# subtraction returning null value mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

```
UPDATE student as s
LEFT JOIN takes as t 
     ON s.ID = t.ID
LEFT JOIN course as c 
     ON t.course_id = c.course_id
SET s.tot_cred = s.tot_cred - c.credits
WHERE t.grade = 'F' OR t.grade IS NULL
```

I am trying to update tot_cred in student by subtracting the credit value of any class the student has failed, grade in takes relation = 'F', or is currently taking, grade in takes relation IS NULL.

The query above however sets tot_cred to NULL for any of the students who meet this criteria and I cannot figure out why.

I apologize if this has been asked before, I tried to search for something relevant but couldn't find many issues related to subtraction. I am new to stackoverflow. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `COALESCE` on `c.credits`

```
set s.tot_cred = s.tot_cred - COALESCE(c.credits,0)
```

Comment: It worked for  of the null values and a grade F, there are 3 more null occurrences however. I do not believe it is the COALESCE that is causing that problem though. I will look at my query and try to figure it out. Thank you for the help with that issue!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) like @JW answer, or use [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull):

```
UPDATE student as s
LEFT JOIN takes as t 
     ON s.ID = t.ID
LEFT JOIN course as c 
     ON t.course_id = c.course_id
SET s.tot_cred = s.tot_cred - IFNULL(c.credits, 0)
WHERE t.grade = 'F' OR t.grade IS NULL
```